# Relative path base_url for packages

Tags: symfony4

I am trying to set packages for assets.

Under my `public` directory I have `css`, `js` direactories.

What I want to achieve is to use packages like:

```
{{ asset('style.css', 'css') }}
```

what needs to point to my `/assets/css/style.css`

Anyway, the `yml` configuration is works only if I give the whole URL.

`framework.yml`:

```
framework:
    ...

    assets:
        packages:
            css:
                base_urls: 'http://myhost.lh/assets/css/'
```

In this case css loads. But if I am using:

```
base_urls: '/assets/css/'
```

or

```
base_urls: 'assets/css/'
```

it doesn't.

Is it possible resolve this? I do not want to hardcoded the domain anywhere in my code because of portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `base_path` option instead of `base_url` as stated [in the manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#packages).

```
framework:
    assets:
        packages:
            css:
                base_path: '/assets/css/'
```